# How to make a search box that doesn't trigger a dropdown

Tags: html, css

The page I'm developing is this: http://www.thespeaker.ca/

I have a search box in the drop-down menu link (I'm using a drop down after using a lot of other menu styles -- I know the drop down is kind of ugly and quite "beta" but it is light code-wise).

I've tried doing what I use for the clickable "S" button at the left, which is wrapping the image in this span:

```
<span data-href="http://www.thespeaker.ca/" onclick="document.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-href'); return false;">
```

But it doesn't seem to work for the search box.

Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: Doesn't the html attribute `autocomplete="off"` work for you?

Comment: When I click on search bar getting drop-down same as when I click on logo and menu. So you doesn't want drop-down on-click on search-bar.

Comment: The problem is that the search input is inside of `<a id="#accordion1">`. So every time you click the search input, the javascript that opens the drop-down menu is triggered. The easiest solution would be to change the header so that the search input is not within the same element. This requires you changing the header.php file in the wordpress theme. Is this your own theme?

Comment: Hi @Italy Grudev no it doesn't. Just tried adding it to every element involved in the search bar. ////// correct frnt I want everything to work as it does, but when you click the search box, it should not trigger the menu (so that you can enter your query term) ////// That isn't the problem, Joseph it is the issue - If I wanted to do that, this question wouldn't exist, would it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the top accordion menu from opening when clicked on the search box, add a `onclick="return false"` to the input element.

```
<input value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" type="text" onclick="return false">
```

It blocks the onclick event to be sent to parent accordion within the search box.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But not the search box. It had to be added to the "input type" (Adding it to the search box does prevent the menu from opening, but also the search function from working).

Comment: By search box I meant the `<input>` element.